# Breadcrubs in PHP using "foreach"

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, breadcrumbs

I have an application that has an included header file in each page. The pages are not organised into folder dues to the nature of my app and because included files within pages tend to break.

So I am trying to use breadcrumbs by having two arrays about the header include. One with the page names and one with their corresponding URLs, as so:

```
$breadCrumbs=array("Department Managment", "Class Managment"); //The breadcrumb page names
$breadLinks=array("/department.php","/class.php"); //The breadcrumb URLs
require_once "../include/headers.php"; //Include header
```

What I really need help with is the foreach loop. Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
foreach ($breadCrumbs as $bc){
        foreach ($breadLinks as $bl){
echo ("<li class='ELEMENT-crumb'><a href='" . $bl ."'>" . $bc . "</a></li>");}} ?>
```

However this returns four breadcrumbs in this order:

Department Managment - /department.php

Department Managment - /class.php

Class Managment - /department.php

Class Managment - /class.php

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of accomplishing this is to use *one* array which uses the descriptions as keys and the URL's as their associated values. Then you need only one loop:

```
// Array indexed by page name
$breadCrumbs=array(
  "Department Managment" => "/department.php",
  "Class Managment" => "/class.php"
);

// Loop over the array only once
foreach ($breadCrumbs as $page => $url) {
  // Using htmlspecialchars() in case it includes <,>,& etc...
  echo ("<li class='ELEMENT-crumb'><a href='" . $url ."'>" . htmlspecialchars($page) . "</a></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
$link1 = array("name" => "Department Management", "link" => "/department.php");
$link2 = array("name" => "Class Management", "link" => "/class.php");

$breadcrumbs = array($link1, $link2);

foreach($breadcrumb as $link) {
    echo '<li class="ELEMENT-crumb"><a href="' + $link["link"] + '">' + $link["name"] + '</a></li>';
}
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work.